# How to draw multiple circle inside each other using canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I need to draw multiple circle inside each other like on the image below and I am puzzled on how to do it.
Please help!!!!

[image: 1]

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function drawRedCircle() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("Circle");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var circle = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 70, 0, Math.PI * 2,);
    circle.fillStyle = "red";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();
    

    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 160, 0, Math.PI * 2,);
    circle.fillStyle = "yellow";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();


    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2,);
    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
    ctx.lineWidth=25;
    circle.closePath();
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="drawRedCircle()">
<h1> Draw A Red Circle Using The Canvas Element </h1>
<canvas id="Circle" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;">
Your browser does not support the Canvas tag.
</canvas>



</body>
</html>
```

## Draw A Red Circle Using The Canvas Element

Your browser does not support the Canvas tag.

Answer (score 0):

I see several mistakes

#### 1. You use "ctx" by mistake instead of "circle"

I have corrected this.

#### 2. You have filed to draw the biggest item first.

As a result the bigger items overwrite the smaller ones. I have re-ordered them so the biggest goes first.

```js
function drawRedCircle() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Circle");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var circle = canvas.getContext("2d");

    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 160, 0, Math.PI * 2, );
    circle.fillStyle = "yellow";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();


    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 70, 0, Math.PI * 2, );
    circle.fillStyle = "red";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();


    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, );
    circle.strokeStyle = "blue";
    circle.lineWidth = 25;
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="drawRedCircle()">
  <h1> Draw A Red Circle Using The Canvas Element </h1>
  <canvas id="Circle" width="500" height="500" style="background-color: blue; border: 1px solid black;">
Your browser does not support the Canvas tag.
</canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanx to your help I manged to draw separate nested circles and nested squares but how do i nest circles inside of the squares please?I am sorry to be a pain